# How do I describe a local function to (trace)?

Tags: debugging, common-lisp, trace

In common lisp, the function (trace name) can be used to see output about the calls to a function.

If my function is declared with local scope, how do I describe it to trace?

eg, how do I trace bar, below:

```
(defun foo (x)  
  (labels ((bar (y) (format t "bar: ~a~&" y)))  
    (bar x)))
```

Comment: Local functions have no tracing, no docstrings, no independent redefinition of their parent. You give up a lot. For that reason, they better have a good reason to be local: and that good reason is ... drum roll ... requiring access to the parent function's lexical environment.  Your `bar` function above doesn't; it can be trivially moved outside of `foo` to stand alone as a toplevel function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracing local functions with `(TRACE ...)` is not defined by ANSI Common Lisp.

Some implementations have extensions to do that. See for example [CMU CL](http://common-lisp.net/project/cmucl/doc/cmu-user/debugger.html).

Other than that, you would need add some code to the definition of FOO. For example it might be useful to have a macro so that you can write the call to bar as (trace-it (bar x)) and the macro would expand into code that prints the entry and exit.

Answer (score 3):

As there is no standard way of tracing local functions, the way I'd go about the problem is by writing a `tracing-labels` macro that implements tracing, transforming the following:

```
(defun foo (x)  
  (tracing-labels ((bar (y) (format t "bar: ~a~&" y)))  
    (bar x)))
```

into something like this:

```
(defun foo (x)
  (labels ((bar (y)
             (format *trace-output* "~&ENTER: ~S" 'bar)  ;'
             (multiple-value-prog1
                 (progn (format t "bar: ~a~&" y))
               (format *trace-output* "~&LEAVE: ~S" 'bar))))  ;'
    (bar x)))
```